# In datagridview i used for loop to store values in the right row. It show index was out of range error?

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{                    
   if (row["ProductId"].ToString().Contains(searchValue))
   {
       for (int i = 1; i <= table.Rows.Count; i++)
       {                            
            MessageBox.Show("Product Id: " + row["ProductId"].ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString());

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = row["ProductId"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = row["ProductName"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = row["ProductType"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = row["CreateDate"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = row["UpdateDate"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = row["IsActive"].ToString();
       }
   }
}
```

I'm using a datagridview; I use a `for` loop to store row values but I get the following error:

> index was out of range

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your

```
int i = 1; i <= table.Rows.Count
```

should be

```
int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count
```

because your rows index starts with `0` and keeps until `table.Rows.Count - 1`, that's why you don't have index as `Rows[table.Rows.Count]`, last index will be `Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1]`

Next time, please debug your code and check your each index that your datagridview has it or not.

Related;

- [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @mani Are you sure you have `6` column? On which line you get this error? What is the value of `i` when you get this error?

Comment: I think its an error to assign to cell values  "row["xxx"].ToString()". Doing that, you change the "int" or "DateTime" value types to "string". So remove the ".ToString()".

Comment: Beside my previous remark, It is surprising that you loop on DataTable in the "for each" and again on "for int i". Doesn't the "for i" loop refer to DataGridView rowsCount ?